# Apply regex on line substring

Tags: regex, sed, sublimetext3

Given a line such as:

```
<String id="blah"><a href="#" class="btn">Download</a></String>
```

I pretend to change it into:

```
<String id="blah">&lt;a href="#" class="btn"&gt;Download&lt;/a&gt;</String>
```

That is, I want to apply the substitutions
1) `<` to `&lt;`, and
2) `>` to `&gt;`
only to the text enclosed within the `String` tag.

Is it possible to do that in one line?

Note: I'm just using sublime for the text replacement. What I'm after is for a sed-like regex.

Update: you can get anything within the `String` tag, not only `<a href...>...</a>` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>
```

- `<a` matches `<a` in the string
- `(.*?)>` matches everything *(if exists)* until `>` character
- `(.*?)<\/a>` matches everything *(if exists)* until `</a>` characters

And then replace it with following pattern to make expected result:

```
&lt;a$1&gt;$2&lt;/a&gt;
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xK6dW6/1)

---

### Edit

According to comments, here is a regular expression which matches everything between `<String>` tag and replaces `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`:

```
/<String(.*?)>(.*?)<([^>]*)>(.*?)<(.*?)><\/String>/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xK6dW6/2)

---

**Note:** You also can use `/g` modifier to make it as global.  All matches *(don't return on first match)*

Comment: Brilliant Shafizadeh. I wind the question up a bit because, as usual, I wasn't too explicit with the requirements. Could we go for a solution not tied to having a `<a...>...</a>` within the `String` tag.

Comment: @rturrado I'm not sure what you need exactly, please add a few examples *(plus expected result)* to your question .. then I will update my answer according to your update.

Comment: I just want to change all the `<` and `>` within a `<String></String>` tag. Your solution assumes I've got a `<a></a>` tag inside the `String` tag; but I can have any text there, e.g.: `blah`, `blah < >`, `<li>blah</li>`, and so on. The substitutions for those three examples should be `blah`, `blah &lt; &gt;`, `&lt;li&gt;blah&lt;/li&gt;`.

Comment: Thanks Shafizadeh. Could you explain a bit your answer? Why all the capturing groups?

Comment: I cannot accept your solution. In your last pattern, you assume there will be two tags (enclosed within < and >) within the String tags. I could have *anything* there (to be a bit more specific I could say *any XML* code). For example `a>b<cd>>ef<<`